# Why did Hutch take the painting?

Tags: plot-explanation, nobody

In the movie, *Nobody* (2021), Hutch burns the Russian mafia hideout and takes one painting with him. He carries the painting through several dangerous situations and gunfights, which seems risky.

When Hutch is arrested by police, while he is feeding a cat, we can see the painting is still with him, covered in splattered blood. It is obviously important to him.

Why did he take it and what does he plan to do with it?

Comment: How is what he does with it important as a plot point or in better understanding the plot?

Comment: @CGCampbell, I haven't seen the film, but the point in asking Q's like this, is to see if there is answer that is relevant to better understand plot. It seems legit to me, if a character takes something they deem important, that the audience would ask what was done with said object. How that fits into the film or what it says about the character, would make some objects important. Too many times I see people trying to demote questions, deeming them trivia, before anyone has a chance to even see if the Q has answer!

Comment: @DarthLocke Thank you for that. In actuality, that is _exactly_ why I asked the question. As it stands, this question has every likelihood as to be closed for those same reasons. I was attempting to get the OP to add a reason(s) to enable us to better understand why we should care.

Comment: @CGCampbell But then the OP would already have an answer. Not everyone who asks a Q knows the answer to their Q ahead of time! As it turns out there is a reasonable answer that relates to the plot after all. I just think that *sometimes, when one contest a Q in such a way, it comes off as an attack, because clearly someone is looking for answer. Most are not trying to pull a fast one to score points. It might of been better to instead to of asked for more context about the Q, than assume the Q is trivia, simply because one felt it lacked better understanding.

Comment: Sigh. You and I are talking past each other. I know how many questions here get closed as trivia and I was trying to help the OP avoid that fate. Getting him to put a reason we might want to know what happened to the painting might help those who consider it trivia to not close it. You know what, fine, chastise me all you want. I probably should have been more eloquent in my original comment.

Comment: I think the question could be better worded. for example: "why did hutch take the painting?" with a possible addition "what did he plan to do with it". What he does in the future is presumably part of why he took it which is clearly about his motivation which is totally relevant to interpreting the movie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

My assumption would be that he took the famous painting Vincent van Gogh's "the bedroom" from the Russian mafia and it was something he could take away after losing all his money, his business, and his gold. This would give him enough money to live off the grid.

Comment: awesome, thank you for identifying this picture. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said I would imagine it would cover 'his expenses' but his face seemed to show that it resonated with him - might just be he liked it and decided to keep it rather than burn it up with the others (which was a waste).

I dare say Hutch has other resources stashed away for a rainy day.

Answer (score -1):

The painting was a Van Gogh worth over $100 million by todays valuation. Since the Russian Mob owned it was likely stolen.

The last phone call Hutch took was likely the US Government giving him a new assignment. The US Government would arrange return of the Painting to the Insurance Owner. Customary bounties are as high as 20%. It’s likely that Hutch received between $5 to $20 million as a reward.

It’s also noteworthy that Hutch could have helped himself to $10 million or more of the Russian Obshak cash. He proffered $5 to $10k of the cash at the nightclub, implying he got more. Also the new home was a major upgrade to the tract housing he lived in prior.

Comment: What new information does this add that wasn’t already covered in the accepted answer?

Answer (score -2):

Those who identified the painting are correct...the reason for Hutch taking it is not for the money however.  You can't just go sell a $60m Van Gogh that easily without attracting attention.  The reason that Hutch took the painting is the same reason that Van Gogh painted it.  It eased Van Gogh's mind and gave him solace, depicting his simple bedroom in his house at Arles, after a severe period of depression.  It also symbolized the beginning of some pretty turbulent and psychotic times in Van Gogh's life...

Comment: What new information does this add that wasn’t already covered in the accepted answer?

Answer (score -3):

I just saw This movie. An entertaining pleasure. Very nice.
But why this painting? Who is the artist?

Anyone who knows a little about the style of well-known, expensive artists will recognize the big name here. **Van Gogh**. (At first, I thought I saw a Spitzweg, which confused me even more - thanks to the search engine for the clarification)

Anyone who's known a little bit more (Or questioned the machine here as well), recalls a spectacular art theft in the Netherlands 30 years ago. 20 paintings disappeared from a museum in Amsterdam with the value of hundreds of millions of dollars and the perpetrator was imprisoned. Paintings were lost, unknown however.

One of their paintings:  this picture- Van Gogh's "the bedroom"

Nobody "Hutch" didn't pick just anyone. He took what was probably the most valuable.

However, many questions remain unanswered.

Comment: Hi! It seems the accepted answer pretty much says the same. What else can you add to make this answer different?